# How do I update TABLE1 with values from TABLE2 without setting columns from TABLE1 to specific, individual select statements?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, sql-update

I want to update one table with a values from another table if those values exist. I am using a `RunSqlTasklet` in Spring to run this SQL, but will be actually using postgres and my version can't handle merges, so no merge answers please.

**Example:**

[image: TABLE1]

[image: TABLE2]

After the update, I want table 1 to look like below
[image: TABLE1_updated]

The below works but doing the individual, specific column select part over and over, seems like it could be improved.

```
UPDATE schema.TABLE1 t1
SET  COLUMN1 = (SELECT t2.COLUMN1 FROM schema.TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4 AND t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5)
    ,COLUMN2 = (SELECT t2.COLUMN2  FROM schema.TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4 AND t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5)
    ,COLUMN3 = (SELECT t2.COLUMN3 FROM schema.TABLE2 t2 WHERE  t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4 AND t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5)
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1 FROM schema.TABLE2 t2 
              WHERE t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4
              AND t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5
              );
```

How do I update the above query to update TABLE1 with values from TABLE2 without setting columns from TABLE1 to specific,individual select statements above?

I have Googled and the above is the only thing that seemed to work, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update-join syntax. Basically, you just need to add a `from` clause with table2, and a `where` clause with the join condition (and any other condition you may want, of course):

```
UPDATE schema.TABLE1 t1
SET    t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN1,
       t1.COLUMN2 = t2.COLUMN2,
       t1.COLUMN3 = t2.COLUMN3
FROM   schema.TABLE2 t2
WHERE  t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4 AND t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, again I am running a batch job in spring with a RunSqlTasklet and I am getting this error "StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar " with code "[42000-192]" and the query I am essentially using is below:  UPDATE schema.TABLE1 t1
  SET t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN2
     FROM schema.TABLE2 t2
     WHERE t1.COLUMN4 = t2.COLUMN4    .....This simple test query did not seem to work, is there anything that is potentially missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this too

```
--Select *
Update T1 
SET    t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN1,
       t1.COLUMN2 = t2.COLUMN2,
       t1.COLUMN3 = t2.COLUMN3
 from schema.Table1 T1 Inner JOIN
      schema.Table2 T2
           on T1.Column4 =T2.Column4 and t1.COLUMN5 = t2.COLUMN5
```

Comment: This did not seem to work either, and I am inclined to think this is something with H2

Comment: No. Do **not** repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause.